# ¿Cómo presionar 7 veces la tecla 'Tab' con Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Resulta que trabajo con un **formulario** en donde realizo ciertas acciones **ejecutando código Javascript**, con la extensión de Chrome, **'Shortkeys(Custom Keyboard Shortcuts)'**. La configuro para que al presionar cierta tecla realice una acción.

Por ejemplo:

Al presionar <kbd>Enter</kbd>, la extensión dispara este código, el cual hace clic en un botón con ese ID para agregar un producto:

```
agregarProducto = document.getElementById("append_item");
agregarProducto.click();
```

Al presionar <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd> ejecuta el siguiente código para hacer foco en el campo de texto de 'Cliente':

```
document.getElementById("venta_cliente").focus();
```

Ahora, mi intención es tener un código de Javascript que **simule presionar la tecla 'Tab' 7 veces** para disparar dicho código con otra tecla configurada en **'Shortkeys(Custom Keyboard Shortcuts)'**.

(Actualmente solucioné esto con AutoHotKey, en Windows, pero necesito implementar esta solución en Ubuntu y quería hacerlo a través de esta extensión de Chrome).

**Me cerraron la pregunta** por esta otra [Simular la presión de una tecla con Javascript | Typescript](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/558065/simular-la-presi%c3%b3n-de-una-tecla-con-javascript-typescript) (Simular la presión de una tecla con Javascript | Typescript) pero no es lo que busco, la cuestión es que donde quiero ejecutar el script es una web de un tercero, la cual tiene etiquetas sin ID, ni nada a lo que recurrir para enlazar el código. Por otro lado necesito **Javascript puro** ya que **la extensión no reconoce Typescript.**

Comment: Èl codigo de la pregunta enlazada, es JS puro.. TS es un superset de js.. podes escribir el js obviando totalmente TS... ahora, la pregunta habla de otro problema.. probaste el codigo???